# Choosing a JavaMail "local store provider"

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I'm looking at using javamail to download email/gmail using imap in a swing application.

According to the FAQ on javamail http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#localprovs I'm going to need a "local store provider", does anyone have any recommendations or advice on ones to avoid / choose?

I had presumed that I would just store the messages in a database - is that a bad idea?

I'm really looking for the simpest solution I can find - but actually works!

Answer (score 2):

Both JavaMailDir and Plexus mentioned in the other answers should work.  However, I will add that after working with both (for reading messages from an actual inbox, not just as a local store) JavaMailDir seems to have some issues running on Windows.  Particularly with the fact that the ".INBOX" folder begins with a dot.

Answer (score 1):

[JavaMaildir](http://javamaildir.sourceforge.net/) seems to be simple enough as you want [from the examples](http://javamaildir.sourceforge.net/examples/)

The full list of providers is [on the Sun website](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/Third_Party.html).

Answer (score 0):

Two providers I know:

1. [Mstor](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/mstor/index.php?title=Main_Page): mbox provider
2. [plexus](http://svn.plexus.codehaus.org/browse/plexus/trunk/plexus-sandbox/plexus-maildir-): maildir provider, not much doc available